# how can i store a series of 2 integers with default collection API's in java

Tags: java, collections

I want to store a series of numbers but using Collection APIs in java i don't want to use the standard two dimensional array, so how can i do the same.

`ArrayList<Integer,Integer>` 
I want to do something like this, so what method should i use.

Comment: Probably you want a Map: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: you can wrap your (Int,Int) in one object (say MyObject), then declare `ArrayList<MyObject>`. Tada !

Comment: Basically two dimensional array allows you to store **single** value accessed by composite `[ i ][ j ]` index; that is not the same as `Collection<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`. Could you please clarify the use case?